# Поделить одну целую фигуру svg на 2 в Inkscape

Tags: svg, inkscape

Есть одна цела фигура. Необходимо ее поделить на две, так чтобы визуальна фигура была таже только уже состоящая из двух элементов.

Есть две координаты, два узла между которыми необходимо провести линию и по этой линии поделить фигуру.

Возможно ли выполнить это в Inkscape, как?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сначала проводиться линия, где надо разрезать фигуру, затем применяют метод division. Видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1RpqgzC6hQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделай копию фигуры и удали все узлы слева у одной и все узлы справа у другой:

Выделяешь 1 узел инструментом "*Изменить узлы контура...*.". Нажимаешь "*разорвать контур в выделенных узлах*". Выделяешь точку 2 и тоже. Снимаешь выделение с узла и выделяешь контур щелчком по линии. нажимаешь del. На оставшемся куске Выделяешь подвешенные узлы и нажимаешь "*соединить контуры по выделенным оконечным узлам новым сегментом*"

Или

Включаешь прилипание к узлам. Отрезком "*Рисовать кривые безье и прямые линии*" соединяешь две точки. Выделяешь фигуру, потом отрезок. Нажимаешь меню *Контур -> разделить (ctrl+/)*